# Fetching image url from jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to give a src attribute to a created  element. The src should be a url retrieved from the giphy api. I can console.log the response data and everything is fine, however I cannot seem to get the jQuery for creating an element to house the gif correct.

```
$('.spawn-button').on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: query + $(this).html() + APIKey + limit,
    method: 'GET'
  }).done(function(response) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
      // console.log(response.data[i]);
      // console.log(response.data[i].images.original);
      $('.gif-container').append("<img src=" + response.data[i].images.fixed_height + ">");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can you show an example of `response`

Comment: Try this `$('.gif-container').append("<img src='" + 
    response.data[i].images.fixed_height +"'>");
    }`

Comment: that didnt work... i am getting a GET ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: According to the [API docs](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/#sample-responses), `fixed_height` is an object, so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to append

Comment: I am trying to get the url from that object and make new img with that url as the source

Comment: Then use `response.data[i].images.fixed_height.url`

Comment: What is the issue here?  Is image element getting added in the DOM, which i doubt,

Comment: hahaha i forgot to add the .url extension. That did it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the below code . as per the documentation at https://developers.giphy.com/docs/  fixed_height object has the `url` property for the GIF image

```js
$('.spawn-button').on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: query + $(this).html() + APIKey + limit,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
      // console.log(response.data[i]);
      // console.log(response.data[i].images.original);
      $('.gif-container').append("<img src=" + response.data[i].images.fixed_height.url + ">");
    }
  });
});
```